# ElasticSearch on Azure - VM Availability Set vs Scale Set

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, azure-virtual-machine

We've deployed an ElasticSearch cluster via Azure Marketplace (the "Self-Managed" flavor) it deploys the cluster as a VM Availability Set.  However, we want to be able to scale up the number of data nodes when needed, similar to how we can do with our other VM Scale Sets (very easy to accomplish in Azure). Reading the article here: https://www.elastic.co/blog/deploying-elasticsearch-on-microsoft-azure (see the last paragraph of the "Availability" section), it even mentions taking this approach, although it doesn't give instructions on how to accomplish this (the Scale Sets link just leads to a general description of VM scale sets).

Does anyone know how to get ElasticSearch set up in Azure as a Scale Set instead of Availability Set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for running ElasticSearch on Azure VMSS.

It is not a trivial task as you need gracefully add/remove nodes into Elastic Search cluster.

There is a template that allows to install Elasticsearch cluster on a Virtual Machine Scale Set.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/elasticsearch-vmss/